# Помощь с ссылками на метод

Tags: java, ссылки, лямбда-выражение

Вообщем, вот такая вот задача:

```
class T{
    void doSmth(int param){}
}
```

Далее мы создаем обьект этого класса:

```
T t = new T();
```

Нужно , чтобы работали две фичи :

```
T::doSmth
t::doSmth
```

Со вторым случаем все понятно(Создаем функциональный интерфейс)
Вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтобы заработала первая ссылка(здесь имеется ввиду структура ИмяКласса::ИмяМетода). Начальные данные изменять нельзя. Заранее спасибо добрым людям!!

Comment: при чем здесь "лямбда-выражение"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то может быть это вам подойдёт:

```
class T {
    void doSmth(int param) { }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    void doSomething(T obj, int param);
}

...

SomeInterface interfaceInst = T::doSmth;
T classInstance =  new T();
interfaceInst.doSomething(classInstance,1);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно чтобы метод `doSmth` был статическим.

Comment: С этим понятно, но мне нужно вызвать именно не статический метод через Имя класса, в котором он находиться